# TcpClient still connected after server closed connection. Why?

Tags: c#, tcp, connection, tcpclient

I have a TCP server running serving TCP clients - crazy, I know. Now I have a behavior that is not clear to me and maybe someone could help me understanding it.

```
[Test]
[TestCase(2, 1)] // first scenario: Okay!
[TestCase(1, 1)] // second scenario: Huh?
public void NotifyClientAboutError(int clientSendBytes, int serverReadBytes)
{
    var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
    server.Start();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (var serverClient = server.AcceptTcpClient())
        {
            using (var serverClientStream = serverClient.GetStream())
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < serverReadBytes; i++)
                {
                    serverClientStream.ReadByte();
                }
                serverClientStream.Close();
            }
            serverClient.Close();
        }
    });

    using (var client = new TcpClient())
    {
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 12345);
        using (var clientStream = client.GetStream())
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < clientSendBytes; i++)
            {
                clientStream.Write(new byte[] { 42 }, 0, 1);
            }

            // returns 0 - would have expected an Exception here
            clientStream.ReadByte();

            // says: true
            Console.WriteLine(client.Connected);

            // no exception
            clientStream.Write(new byte[] { 42 }, 0, 1);
            clientStream.Flush();

            // says: true
            Console.WriteLine(client.Connected);
        }
    }

    server.Stop();
}
```

See the two scenarios wrapped in NUnit test cases:

**First:** When *the server reads less bytes* than the client sent, then closes the connection by calling `Close()` on the stream, the following call to `ReadByte()` fails with an exception. So far so good. That is what I expect.

**Second:** When *the server reads all bytes* sent by the client, then closes the connection, the following call to `ReadByte()` does not fail. It returns `0` and - even more strange - it states being still connected and the client can still write data on the stream without exception.

Can someone explain why the second scenario happens like this? Or how do I manage it, to get an exception in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` returns zero if the peer had sent FIN by doing `close` on its end.

`read` raises an exception ( ECONNRESET ) for RST from peer.

Now:

An entity will send RST if the recv Q is not empty and it attempts `close`. The connection is gone for good.

And if the recv Q is empty, FIN goes out if `close` is attempted. And this does not mean the other end cannot write to the socket. It hasn't called `close` yet. The connection is half-open. Hence, your observation of client being able to write to the socket.

Comment: Thanks so far, this clears it up a bit. Now, this means a RST on an empty queue is somewhat senseless and a `0` from `Read` is equivalent to *>No one is listening on the remote side any more. Stop Talking.<*? Or are there circumstances this would happen?

Comment: `0` on `read` does not mean no one is listening on the remote side. It just means the remote end is **done sending data**. And it does not mean stop talking to me as well.